# Legacy PC mode errors when repairing GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed Windows 7 on a separate partition.  While I can boot up Windows, I cannot boot up Ubuntu anymore.  I created the Boot Repair Disk to repair GRUB for dual booting (Ubuntu being the default OS) but I get the error that my PC is in Legacy Mode and should be switched to EFI.  I started up in BIOS and changed the boot options from Auto to EFI, yet I get the same error message.  I do have a link generated from Boot Repair.  I am looking for any guidance to resolve the EFI issue.  Thanks!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/19836025/